# Can't change the size of a TableView in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder

I'm trying to change the size of a tableView I have in interface builder and can't seem to. When I first started the app I could drag it around and stretch the sides but all of a sudden I can't adjust it. I tried to delete my tableView and add a new one but the same thing happened. Thanks in advance. Here's what I see when I try to change the size: 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

if your using a UIViewController you can drag and drop a tableView and can place in a custom position you want. but if your using a UITableViewController you cant move the tableView to your custom position. if you want to do it in UITableViewController you can do like below

if you want your tableView content should show from a point, that you want you can do this way,

```
  [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(100,0,0,0)];
```

else  if you want set your tableView to a frame in UITableViewController you do this way,

```
  - (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews
  {
      [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
      self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,100,320,300);
  }
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of view controller are you using to manage your table view? Since you show "prototype cells", I'm guessing it's a UITableViewController. Those are built to fill the entire screen with a single table view (which has always annoyed me.)

Starting with iOS 6, though, you can create a "container" view in another view controler, and then drag an embed segue from your container view onto the table view controller. That does all the housekeeping to make the table view controller a child view controller of the other one, and then you can make it whatever size you want.

If you don't want to use a UITableViewController as a child of another view controller, you can use a regular view controller and wire up the data source and delegate methods yourself. However, things like static table views and prototype cells don't work then.

Comment: It's actually a regular UIViewController. It's been working fine this way until today when I added a tab bar that covered a UItextField I needed. Since then its been haywire.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps someone still coming across this problem.  What I did was make sure the UIViewController had a UIView as its direct child, then dragged the UITableView as a child of the UIView, this allowed me to resize the UITableView.